# Private Chatter Group is visible for other User who is not a member of the group

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

We are having an issue in PROD inwhich User A has created a private group "ABC" inwhich he has added 6 members.But User C who is not even a member of the Private Group "ABC" still able to see and post comments in the private group.I have checked the profile of User C he does not have View all and Modify all permission.
Anybody suggest why this is happening? 
Any other settings that I need to check??

Comment: Also check permission set assigned to this user.  Users with the “Manage All Data” permission can also join private groups directly and change group settings.

Comment: @ TusharSharma  Checked the permission set,User does not have "Modify All Data Permission".

Comment: its` Manage all data` permission

Comment: Can you please tell me where do i find the "Manage All Data" Permission As per my understanding Manager all Data includes View All as well as Modify All and is related to System Admin if I am mistaken...Please suggest..